# Instabug: Disable user location tracking

Tags: android, ios, location, instabug

My team uses the Instabug APK on Android (and iOS) and we'd like to disable user location tracking since we don't need it. I can't find anywhere how to do so.

How does Instabug even track the user's location to begin with? Our app doesn't have any location permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries add automatically the permissions they need. Final manifest file is a merge of  your app's manifest file and all libraries'.

You can check the merged manifest by using `Android Studio > AndroidManifest.xml > Merged Manifest tab`

or

```sh
ANDROID_SDK_PATH/build-tools/28.0.3/aapt d permissions yourApp.apk
```

You can remove the location permission by adding `tools:node="remove"`.

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests

Comment: That's a good idea, but in this case the library is somehow deriving the location without the permission. None of the location permissions appear in our merged manifest.

My guess would be that it's guessing based off the name of the user's time zone and their locale.

Comment: There are some tricks to detect the location without GPS. Inroom locations can be detected by using only WIFI SSID's. If InstaBug creates a graph of WiFi SSIDs and well-known locations, the application can predict the location.